# How can I Change the font size and family of a XAML PivotItem header in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I added a Pivot control to my Windows Phone 8 app, and I want to change the font size and font family of just the Pivot Items. I am working in blend, i would prefer if the answers can be given in relation to Blend for visual studio.

```
<phone:Pivot HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="689" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="436">
            <phone:PivotItem CacheMode="{x:Null}">

                <Grid/>
            </phone:PivotItem>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an Option, you can edit your xaml like this way

```
<phone:PivotItem CacheMode="{x:Null}">
                <phone:PivotItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="PHOTOS" FontSize="30" FontFamily="Consolas"/>
                </phone:PivotItem.Header>
                <Grid/>
            </phone:PivotItem>
```